# if $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to\mathbb{R}$ Showing $f$ is constant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

if $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to\mathbb{R}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}$

show that $f$ is independent of second variable.

if  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$ for all $(x,y) \in\mathbb{R^2}$. then $f$ is constant.

how can we approach this problem. i think we need to show $f(x,y_1)=f(x,y_2)$ for all $y_1,y_2 \in\mathbb{R}$ for the first part.
but how to do that ??
any hint

Comment: For a function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, if $g'=0$, then $g$ is constant. Can you apply this here?

Comment: Try to define one variable function, and then use thcorresponding result in that case.

Comment: @Wojowu i am done with first part. how to show $f$ is constant in second part

Answer (score 0):

Use the fundamental theorem of calculus [(Link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

First define $g_x(y) = f(x,y)$ by assumption $g_x'(y)=0$. Applying the fundamental theorem we have that $g_x(y)-g_x(0) = \int_{0}^y g_x'(y)dy = \int_0^y 0 dy =0$
It follows that $g_x(y)=g_x(0)$ thus $f(x,y)=f(x,0)$ for every $x,y$. In other words $f$ is independent of $y$.